# Why has sending emails from workflows stopped?

Tags: workflow, email

We have a SharePoint system installed. The customer has changed the email system.

After that emails that are sent out in our code using SPMail, and as the user uses the system work OK.

Mails that are sent as part of a workflow are not sent.

Does anyone know what the difference is between these two ways of sending an email?

Comment: Are alerts being sent out ok?

Comment: Did you change the outgoing email configuration? Did you try restarting timer service?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to go into Central Administration and update the outgoing email settings for the farm to point to the new email server.  You should also check that web application itself is pointing to the new email server as well since the Web Application settings override the farm settings.

You also might want to check your Event Logs and LOGS folder to see if there is more specific information about the error.

Answer (score 5):

Dave has a good answer, however, if this has been done, I would check to make sure that the relay is set up correctly to allow all traffic from the IP addresses of all servers in your farm without authentication. It appears that your code may send credentials while the alerts and OOTB workflow emails are not sent using any particular credentials.

Comment: This is also a good place to check as I have now seen two occasions in the past year where applying a Microsoft update has reset the SMTP relay settings back to the default.

Answer (score 0):

Glad that you already found a solution. But it also happens that workflow hangs on waiting for an event and thus no further events are triggered.

Many of these issues are fixed with Service Packs and [hotfixes](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21066), but sometimes the issue remains. In my case, i had to rearrange workflow logic to workaround these issues and just try it the hard way - will it (sometimes) hang this way or not?.